# Custom path for APFS volume in a external SSD

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, apfs

I have external SSD with APFS volumes inside, when plug-in this automatic mount at `/Volumes/Workspace`. Have a way to define to automatic mount in a predefined path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at current volumes:

```
ls /Volumes
```

Get the UUID of volume:

```
diskutil info /Volumes/[name] | grep UUID
```

Create a folder where you wish add the volume:

```
mkdir -p [/absolute/path/to/folder]
```

Put follow code at `fstab`:

```
echo "UUID=[UUID] [/absolute/path/to/folder] apfs rw" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

The example mount a volume with `apfs` format, but you can use for `ntfs`, `nfs`, etc.

Comment: Every time you eject and put the device, this will be mounted where you defined.